# How to 'repair' my owl slider after destroying it

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I have a product page and for every product is a modal, and for every modal is a owl slider.

When I a product for the first time it shows up well but when I close that product and open another product the owl slider is broken.

I tried (or I feel like I tried) every solution I found on internet but still I can't figure it out.

**Here is my jQuery:**

```
var owlCarousel = $('.owl-carousel');
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
   owlCarousel.owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
     items: 1, 
     margin: 100
  });
 });

 $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
   $('.owl-carousel').trigger('destroy.owl.carousel');
 });
```

I hope I explained my problem well!

*Note: When I open a second product this error shows up every second I wait*

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.e._checkVisibile')
```

Answer (score 1):

On line 620 in owl.carousel.js change this:

```
Owl.prototype.onThrottledResize = function() {
    window.clearTimeout(this.resizeTimer);
    this.resizeTimer = window.setTimeout(this.e._onResize, this.settings.responsiveRefreshRate);
};
```

to this:

```
Owl.prototype.onThrottledResize = function() {
    if(this.e !=null) {
        window.clearTimeout(this.resizeTimer);
        this.resizeTimer = window.setTimeout(this.e._onResize, this.settings.responsiveRefreshRate);
    }
};
```

worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for the `visible` owl carousel element and call `owlCarousel` and `destroy` events on it.

```
var owlCarousel;
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
   owlCarousel = $('.owl-carousel:visible');
   owlCarousel.owlCarousel({
     loop: true,
     items: 1, 
     margin: 100
   });
});
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
   owlCarousel.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but when I use this my whole slider is broken

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?